# How to hide table if a variable empty

Tags: php, html, html-table, hide

I have table with variables in it. I want to hide whole table if the first variable is empty. I want to hide `id="con_industry` (whole table) if `$list_primary_industry` variable is empty. Here is my code:

```
     <table class="admintable" id="con_industry">
     <tr id="con_id_industry1">
     <td class="key"><?php echo JText::_('PRIMARY_INDUSTRY');    
     ?></td<td>echo $list_primary_industry; ?></td></tr>
     </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a check before your table:

```
<?php if(isset($list_primary_industry) && !empty($list_primary_industry)): ?>
<table class="admintable" id="con_industry">
  <tr id="con_id_industry1">
    <td class="key"><?php echo JText::_('PRIMARY_INDUSTRY'); ?></td>
    <td>echo $list_primary_industry; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this: (fixed your code a bit)

```
<? if($list_primary_industry) {?>
     <table class="admintable" id="con_industry">
     <tr id="con_id_industry1">
     <td class="key"><?php echo JText::_('PRIMARY_INDUSTRY');    
     ?></td><td><? echo $list_primary_industry; ?></td></tr>
     </table>
<?}?>
```

Comment: it did not do may be I forgot something. if $jobseeker->name is emty hide the table.<table class="admintable"><tr><td class="key"><label for="name"><?php echo JText::_('JBJOBS_NAME'); ?>:</label></td><td><?php echo ($jobseeker->show_name == 'y') ? $jobseeker->name : JText::_('JBJOBS_NAME_CONFIDENTIAL'); ?></td></tr> 
<tr id="con_photo"><td class="key"><label for="name"><?php echo JText::_('JBJOBS_PHOTO'); ?>:</label></td><td nowrap="nowrap">
<?php echo JBjobs::getLogo($jobseeker->user_id); ?>
</td></tr><?php break;case "contactdetails": ?>
</table>

Comment: Dude, you generally don't post code in to a comment. It's not readable, please re-edit your question or provide a shorter code snippet in the comment.